# regex to check email ids

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regex.
I am checking email ids using regex.

Following is my code to match `<xyz@xyz.com>` with `xyz@xyz.com`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<(.*?)\\>");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<xyz@xyz.com>");
```

And its working fine. Now I want to match either `<xyz@xyz.com>` or `[xyz@xyz.com]` with `xyz@xyz.com`.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<(.*?)>|\\[(.*?)])");
```

Comment: Thanks fo the answer I am getting his syntax Error when I try this code 'Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )'

Comment: Doh! Was in C# mode (where `@` before the string means you don't have to double-backslash). Just corrected by removing `@` and adding a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\[\\<](.*?)[\\]\\>]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("[xyz@xyz.com]");
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Comment: However, this'll also match ```[foo@bar>``` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

firstly `<` or `>` are not special characters for regex so you don't have to use \

**your regex should be like this :**

`"(<|\\])(.*?)\\1"` but this regex does't check email adress is **valid** or **not** if you want to control email is valid or not you will use this regex :

`"(<|\\])([\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4})\\1"`

but you **should not use regex** for email validation

Comment: Technically if a email address contains a `@` char and there is at least 1 char before and after the `@`, then its valid. Im not saying its an existing address just a possible valid address. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+ "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("<abc@abc.com>");
```

*Reference* http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/